# Vue- router view lost the param when routing to the children

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I use with I router for routing between component
and I use with a children routing for routing in the page, but I lost the param that I pass in the parent

this is my router define:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/management', name: 'Management', component: Management,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/managementFlow/:confType',
          component: ManagementFlow,
          children: [
            {
              path: '/listConfiguration/:type',
              component: ListConfiguration,
              props: true
            },
            {
              path: '/bulkConfiguration/:type',
              component: BulkConfiguration,
              props: true
            },
          ],
          props: true,
        },
      ]
    },
  ],
})
```

when I use with the parent - to:"/managementFlow/myConfType" I get the confType.
I get the value in  props: ["confType"],

but when I routing in the parent to the child I lost the param confType

```
pathForRouting = `/listConfiguration/${this.type}`;
this.$router.push({
        path: pathForRouting
      });
```

I get the param only in the child:
props: ["type"],

Comment: What's your children full path? `/management/managementFlow/:confType/listConfiguration/:type`?

Comment: right, this is the full name, but in the link I see only /listConfiguration/MyType

Comment: I the a solution if I can use with the same value for confType and type, If I change the name to the same - foe example: confType to type, it will work well

Comment: "but when I routing in the parent to the child" – how are you doing this?

Comment: I added in the code

Comment: I would go with named routes :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use name conventions, to avoid also issue, when route ending is '/':

```
this.$router.push({name: pathForRouting})
```

router should look like:

```
 path: 'something',
 name: 'pathForRouting',
 component: PublicIndex
```